# TLS mutual authentication on a spefic subdomain

Tags: apache, authentication, ssl, client

I'm not sure if this is the best place to ask this question, or if perhaps it's to vague, but here goes anyway.

I have a web server (Apache) which hosts a personal wiki (dokuwiki), as well as a blog (Wordpress). The wiki is located at "wiki.example.com", whereas the blog is just located at "www.example.com". I'm about implement one way TLS/SSL encryption across the example, however I would also like to set up two way TLS/SSL encryption (client authentication) on only the "wiki.example.com" subdomain so that only specific users with the certificate can access it.

- www.example.com - Anyone can access this
- wiki.example.com - only users with a certificate can access this

Is this possible, and if it is, does anyone have any resources explaining how you would go about setting it up?

Comment: Yes it's possible but an explanation here goes way beyond the scope of a stackoverflow answer

Comment: Thats fair enough. Is it possible that you could point me towards some resources that would help me set it up for myself?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible.

Create two different virtual hosts for both the websites

But for two-way authentication, the virtual host should contain this two parameters enabled

**SSLVerifyClient require**

**SSLCACertificateFile**

You can get free SSl related support on this website [www.ssl.support](https://www.ssl.support)